# 301 redirect old url to new in mobile website

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect the old urls to the seoed urls in the mobile version of the website which is located at `http://www.domain.com/mobile/` and has its own `.htaccess` file with the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos.html$ category.php?cat=$1

RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos-([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ category.php?cat=$1&page=$2&sortby=$3
```

How can i 301 redirect the old urls to new ones?

Comment: What are some examples of old and new URLs?

Comment: old domain.com/mobile/category.php?cat=categoryname
new domain.com/mobile/browse-categoryname-videos-1-date.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mobile/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ browse-%1-videos.html? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos.html$ category.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos-([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ category.php?cat=$1&page=$2&sortby=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: that worked i changed the 302 to 301 to have a permanent redirect but worked perfectly.